# Nginx:proxy_pass with headers

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers

In  my application I've redirected the request from `localhost/api` to another ip which is (http://127.0.0.1:3000/) its working fine now ,but the problem is header is not present in proxy url

```
location /api{
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/;
           proxy_pass_request_headers on; 
         }
```

I got solution for setting header

```
proxy_set_header header_name testval;
```

But i don't want this bcz header value is dynamic its based on user input(Actually its an api key)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have tried it without proxy pass? the header is correctly work?